# Android LAYOUT xml / java error

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I am trying to get a panel which has a canvas containing an image which i will place over another image and when i touch the screen the top(overlaying) image will be erased by means of a PoerterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode) etc ,, anyway I have the functionality done and dusted thanks to the help of a guy on this forum who provided some code which basically carried out exactly what I needed, but I'm having one slight problem,, the guys implementation of the code, will not allow me to reference the Panel class properly in XML to place the Panel on a pre defined XML (main.xml) file. its giving me an error stating

> Custom view Panel is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work

This is what my xml looks like on a basic scale (just the view in place within the outer linearlayout).

```
<com.easyscratch.full.Panel 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id ="@+id/easyCustView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

The java is as followed .( PANEL CLASS)

```
package com.easyscratch.full;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

class Panel extends View
{

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mPaint;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas pcanvas ;
     int x = 0;
     int y =0;
     int r =0;
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);

        Log.v("Panel", ">>>>>>");

        setFocusable(true);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        // setting paint 
             mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAlpha(0);
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

            // getting image from resources
            Resources r = this.getContext().getResources();

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),  R.drawable.foreground_image);

            // converting image bitmap into mutable bitmap

              bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(295, 260, Config.ARGB_8888);

               pcanvas = new Canvas();
              pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);                   // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
              pcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    // draw a circle that is  erasing bitmap            
        pcanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,null);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

         // set paramete to draw circle on touch event
         x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();

            r =20;
            // Atlast invalidate canvas
            invalidate();
            return true;
    }

}
```

BASIC MAIN CLASS CALLING MAIN.XML

```
package com.easyscratch.full;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class easyscratch extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

,, If only Someone cud tell me what im doing wrong , or maybe an alternative implementation of the

```
public Panel(Context context) {
    super(context);
```

anyway thanks alot in advanced really would appriciate some help as soon as possible :)

CHEERS GUYS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor for Panel must also, at least, have an AttributeSet field.

```
public Panel(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
   super.(context, attr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added that but now it doesn't give me the error it just crashes when I launch the app. I use a Galaxy Tab real device to test my app on its 2.2.

Comment: You'll probably have to start up ddms and post the logcat to see what is causing the crash.

Comment: Its fine, I figured it out :) Thanks a lot for your responses!